# The fix is in : Any guesses?

Tags: word, lateral-thinking

> My prefix is in the infix
> My infix is in the suffix
> My suffix is in the prefix
> 3 and 3 totally six

What's the word?

Comment: I've removed the spoilers because theres no point putting them in the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Insure

My prefix is in the infix

> **In** is in **in**fix

My infix is in the suffix

> **Su** is in **su**ffix

My suffix is in the prefix

> **Re** is in p**re**fix

3 and 3 totally six

> In all, **insure** has 3 consonants and 3 vowels, making six letters total.

Comment: Guerr pbafbanagf naq guerr ibjryf

Comment: @DrD Ah, okay, thanks for the info.